# Is there a name for algebras over a field $k$ whose residue class fields have finite dimension over $k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebras

Let $k$ be a field and let $A$ be a $k$-algebra. Assume that for every maximal ideal $P \subseteq A$ the residue class field $A/P$ has finite dimension as a $k$-vector space.

> Is there a name for $k$-algebras like that?

Clearly, finitely generated $k$-algebras $A$ satisfy this property, but what about the case $A$ not finitely generated over $k$?

Examples of such algebras can easily be obtained by localizing finitely generated $k$-algebras:

> For instance let $\mathcal{O} = k[x]_{(x)}$ be the localization of the finite $k$-algebra $k[x]$ by the maximal ideal generated by $x$. Then $\mathcal{O}$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $P$ generated by $x$ which is a non finitely generated $k$-algebra. But it has a finite dimensional residue class field $\mathcal{O}/P \cong k$.

Comment: Now posted on MO: [Is there a name for algebras over a field $k$ whose residue class fields have finite dimension over $k$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/362483) (Adding a link at least in a comment - following the advice given here: [Moderator Supported (Official) Guidelines for “Legitimate” CrossPosting?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5085#5088))

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for your advice and that you've posted the link!